# BASH - selective variable substitution

Tags: bash

I need to replace a variable within a sippet but i have to leave unchanged "$1" in apache virtual host, eg:

```
SNIPPET=$(cat <<- 'EOF'
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${HOSTNAME}
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/${HOSTNAME}

    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/${HOSTNAME}>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php56:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/${HOSTNAME}/$1

</VirtualHost>
EOF
)
```

I need change `${HOSTNAME}` but not `$1`, is possible?

Comment: use backslash to have a literal `$`:  `${HOSTNAME}/\$1`

Comment: Great, works! Sorry but i'm new....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `cat` here; a string can contain embedded newlines.

```
SNIPPET="\
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${HOSTNAME}
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/${HOSTNAME}

    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/${HOSTNAME}>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php56:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/${HOSTNAME}/\$1

</VirtualHost>"
```

In your case, where you wanted at least one parameter substitution, you cannot quote the here-doc delimiter, since that treats the *entire* here-doc as a single-quoted string. Once you remove the quotes, the entire here-doc is treated as a double-quoted string, so you need to escape anything that would otherwise be subject to parameter expansion.